# Android Service process restarted

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I have recently come across an issue in which my `Service` method will call `onCreate()` multiple times. `onDestroy` is not called when this happens. My `Service` is just recreated without notice and my `Service`'s state is reset to as if it started the very first time. I know that Android will kill processes that it needs to free up memory. However, when this happens the lifecycle is still followed and it's trivial to save/restore states.  This is just happening in the middle of execution.

What exactly is causing this?  From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670839/if-android-restarts-a-service-is-oncreate-called-again), it says that onCreate is only called when a process is starting which is how I came to this conclusion.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211066/android-service-oncreate-is-called-multiple-times-without-calling-ondestroy) says to put the Service in a separate process from the rest of the Application, but this didn't work. It also seems hacky.

This is occurring on Android 4.0.4.

Comment: Have you tried making your service a singleton? That way you can only have one instance at a time?

Comment: @Eenvincible: I may need some sort of Singleton to more easily save the state, but I'm concerned as to why this is happening in the first place.